# Transformation of a sphere and computing an integral by using sphere coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, transformation, spherical-coordinates

Let $V \subset\mathbb R^3$be the ellipsoid $$9x^2+4y^2+z^2≤36.$$ How can I express $V$ as a transformation of a sphere and how can I compute the sphere $$\int_v x^2\,d\lambda^3(x,y,z)$$ with sphere coordinates?

A little help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

let
$$x=2\,\rho\,\cos\theta\sin\phi$$
$$y=3\,\rho\,\sin\theta\sin\phi$$
$$z=6\,\rho\,\cos\phi$$
we have
$$\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(\rho,\theta,\phi)}=36\rho^2\sin\phi$$
and
$$V=144\int_{0}^{2\pi }{\int_{0}^{\pi }{\int_{0}^{1}{{{\rho }^{4}}}}}{{\cos }^{2}}\theta \,{{\sin }^{3}}\varphi \,d\rho \,d\phi \,d\theta $$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\iiint_{9x^{2} + 4y^{2} + z^{2} < 36}x^{2}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z} =
\iiint_{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} < 36}\
{x^{2} \over 3^{2}}\,{\dd x \over 3}\,{\dd y \over 2}\,\dd z =
{1 \over 54}\pars{\iiint_{r < 6}{r^{2} \over 3}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z}
\\[3mm] = &\
{1 \over 162}\int_{0}^{6}r^{2}\pars{4\pi r^{2}}\,\dd r
= \color{#f00}{{192 \over 5}\,\pi} \approx 120.6372
\end{align}